# UIImage with NSData initWithData is nil

Tags: ios, uiimage, nsdata

The following code does not seem to load an image.

```
uiTabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] init];
NSData *datatmp = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"newsicon.png"];
UIImage *tmp = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:datatmp];
uiTabBarItem.image = tmp;
```

datatmp is nil (0x000000) and 
the image does exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I. Don't reinwent the wheel. Use `tmp = [UIImage imageNamed:@"newsicon.png"];` instead.

II. `NSData` expects a full file path when being initialized from a file. The following would work (but you don't have to use this anyway, as I just pointed it out):

```
NSString *iconPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"newsicon" ofType:@"png"];
NSData *datatmp = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:iconPath];
```

Comment: +1 for actually explaining why the original code wasn't working (as well as giving the better alternative).

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks. I like to shed some light on what happened and why, not only "gimme teh codez".

Answer (score 3):

Loading an image from a file is best accomplished with:

```
  [UIImage imageNamed: "newsicon.png"];
```